# What's the alternative to this missing package (ebay-global-header-node)?

Tags: react-native, package, create-react-native-app

### Description

I was trying to initiate a sample project

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app sample-app
```

It's throwing this error:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app sample-app
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.scm.corp.ebay.com/cubejs-ebay/ebay-global-header-node.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gen/.npm/_logs/2018-02-02T13_01_50_144Z-debug.log
```

Than I ran that isolated command:

```
/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.scm.corp.ebay.com/cubejs-ebay/ebay-global-header-node.git
```

and this error is thrown:

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.scm.corp.ebay.com:
github.scm.corp.ebay.com: Name or service not known
```

I also did it in a remote server to make sure it was not network problem

### Environment

- `npm ls react-native-scripts`:

  /var/www
  └── (empty)
- `npm ls react-native`:

  /var/www
  └── (empty)
- `npm ls expo`:

  /var/www
  └── (empty)
- `node -v`:

  /var/www
  └── (empty)
- `npm -v`: v8.9.4
- `yarn --version`: 1.3.2
- `watchman version`: watchman: command not found

  1. Operating system: Linux SPDEV1 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `$ npm install -g create-react-native-app`

and after it `$ create-react-native-app sample-app`

Maybe it's because you are trying to do both commands in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and as per suggested by Mateo I tried commands like below.

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app

$ create-react-app sample-app
```

Just removed native, not sure about the difference.

Comment: That's going to work, indeed. But this command in specific will create a React App. Not a React Native App. It's different :)

Comment: Thank for your comment. I am no React expert and wrote what worked for me